# openFileDialog DialogResult always shows NONE when opening .exe file

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am currently coding a "quickstart program" which lets you open an .exe file and start them whenever you click a button. 
For this I used an `openFileDialog` to let the user open the desired .exe files.

Additionally I extract the icons from the .exe to show it, above the start button.

This enables the user to select a file (.exe) the **DialogResult** of the **openFileDialog** shows **none**. It never shows **OK**, even though I load a normal and working .exe.

Here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            ExtractIcon(path);
        }
    }

    private void ExtractIcon(string filePath)
    {
        Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
            pictureBox1.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
    }
```

Is there any problem with my code or is it because of **DialogResult**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the code something like this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
        string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        ExtractIcon(path);
}
```

Comment: +1 for shortest code, will accept as answer when possible. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to store the return value of `ShowDialog()` in a variable and then compare this to `DialogResult.OK`

```
var result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK){
  string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
  ExtractIcon(path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `DialogResult` variable? Shouldn't it be:

```
var result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    ExtractIcon(path);
}
```